# C Error Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, linked-list

I made this code,following the functions given in the book "Fundamental Of Data Structures in C",I made the following code for implementing a simple linked list,but I  don't seem to get where I am wrong,as the book code is supposed to be correct:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *listpointer;

typedef struct        {

int data;
listpointer link;
}  node;

void print(listpointer first)
 {
while  (first)      {
           printf("%d\n",first->data);
           first=first->link;
}
 }

void addAtFront(listpointer *first,int n)
{
listpointer t=*first,temp;
temp=malloc(sizeof(node));
int i=1;
while (i <= n)  {
                t=t->link;
                i++;
}
if(*first)  {
       temp->link=t->link;
        temp->data=90; 
       t->link=temp;
}
else 
{
      *first=temp;
        temp->link=NULL;
}
}       


listpointer createList( )
{
listpointer first,second;
if(first=malloc(sizeof(node)))  {
           first->data=67;
           if(second=malloc(sizeof(node)))  {
         second->data=65;
         first->link=second;
         second->link=NULL;
           }
}
return first;
  }





    main( )
   {
listpointer first=createList( );
addAtFront(&first,2);
print(first);
   }
```

Comment: Please post a [short, self-contained example that demonstrates your problem](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is the error at compile or run time?  It would be helpful if you posted the *exact* error.  Also, the formatting of the code is horrible.  If its hard for us to read, it must be hard for you to understand too.  Can you edit the question to tidy the code up?

Answer (score 6):

You have this typedef:

```
typedef struct node *listpointer;
```

But you didn't ever define `struct node`.  You have this definition of an anonymous `struct` `typedef`ed to `node`, though:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    listpointer link;
} node;
```

Probably you meant:

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    listpointer link;
} node;
```

Comment: no the book code was the same that I typed.I meant that one only

Answer (score 5):

You define the struct without a tag,

```
typedef struct node *listpointer;

typedef struct        {

int data;
listpointer link;
}  node;
```

so the `struct node` that a `listpointer` is supposed to point to remains an incomplete type.

You should give the struct a tag,

```
typedef struct node { ...
```

then `listpointer` points to a complete object type.

Comment: Not sure is `typedef struct node *listpointer;` allowed before `node` definition **?**

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine. In addition to the typedef, it declares the `struct node` type, so the compiler knows there is such a type. That must of course be defined later if it is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Why I was getting this error was because I had not included the header file which contained the structure definition.